# Could not find FacebookSDK

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

im  just trying to **intall facebook sdk to my phonegap** android project.i followed

1. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

and after intalling fbsdk I have added it under Project

```
                properties->Android->Library
```

section and select the facebooksdk library Im seeing green color tick mark         infront of the added    library. but when i opened Project again

```
        properties->Android window
```

the green tick mark is not displaying under Library section,

**instead I'm seeing red cross mark**..i have added **external jar** files also but 
cant  find out the solutoin.is there any solutions for this ?

Comment: Check these steps https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Answer (score 2):

Following are the steps to include Facebook SDK into android project:

1) Download the Facebook SDK from the https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ and extract it to local drive.

2) Import "facebook" as a android project into your Eclipse, this is your Facebook SDK, and You have to reference it to your android project.

3) Now create your android project.

4) Right click on it, go to Properties-->android and Add the "facebook "Library as a reference to your project. click Apply.

Check the video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-vNi1W4fco

Comment: while importing facebook to eclipse....itz 3 packages showing losts of errors...why did this happing

Comment: com.facebook,com.facebook.internal,com.facebook.widget..these are the pacakages

Comment: the only thing that i suggest you now that you should change your tutorial LMAO.. im not saying this sdk is wrong but you can follow this http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html

Comment: di i successfully intalled sdk but still  seeing red cross mark.in the librarey plz help me